# How to know where a file (like show.aspx ) is used in .NET project in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio

How to determine where a file (like `show.aspx`) is used or addressed in a .NET project in Visual Studio?

I want to know the path through the web pages.

In some editors, it is easy to right click on it's name on solution explorer and you can find it easily one by one.

Comment: As Albert D. Kallal said, your needs can be fulfilled using the search box that comes with the solution. He also extended the tell shift-ctrl-f method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to find the page, then use the search box in the project explorer.

Say I wanted to find a page "Current" somthing.
(I know I have a page called Current "somthing").

so, in project explorer, in the search box, I can type this:

[image]

So, you can "easy" see that I have two pages.

```
 CurrentUsersS.aspx
 CurrentUsers.aspx.
```

Ok, so next question is then lets search the WHOLE project, both code and markup for say CurrentUsersS.aspx, and see where that is used.

So, while in code (or markup) (not from solution exploer).

Then go:

So, shift-ctrl-f

This brings up a global finder.

And we now can do this:

[image]

So, note how we get BOTH code, and markup, and we get a VERY nice summary of ALL places in code, markup etc. that uses/has

```
CurrentUsers
```

So, to look for a page?

Use the solution exploer search bar. - first example.

Then once you found the page, then in code (or markup), do the shift-ctrl-f

to launch the global finder. Type in part (or all) of what you looking for, and the result is a REALLY nice summary/list of the matches. (and of course you can then click on any such match to jump to the code or markup in question).